# How to modify variables passed by value instead of by reference within function in C?

Tags: c

How to modify variables passed by value instead of by reference within function in C?

```
void fun_a(int a, int b) {
  ....
}

int main() {
    int x = 5, y = 6;
    printf("%d, %d", x, y);    // 5, 6

    fun_a(x, y);               // pass by value

    printf("%d, %d", x, y);    // 1, 2

    return 0;
}
```

How to use `fun_a` to change variables?

Is there any way to do it? Though I know it can change variables by passing references easily.

Comment: You can't, you only get a copy, it's not going to propagate back.

Comment: There's no clean way to do it in regular C, that's what "pass by value" means, that you can't affect it. You may patch resulting machine code from compiler afterwards to do it, but that's not generic solution, just per-compilation. (as most of the compilers with optimizations will compile the second `printf` as `puts("5, 6");` to save runtime resources, as the value of `x, y` is known during compilation time, so in such case you would have to patch the machine code to contain different string to output "1, 2")

Comment: Your question is like asking if there is any way to write with a pen held the wrong way round.

Comment: C does not support pass-by-reference. It is always pass-by-value! And your question does not make any sense. THe only explanation is the asker has not understood pass-by-value.

Comment: @tilz0R: Of course and it was given in the very first comment already.

Comment: @tilz0R: I'm not that sure you do. And the edit could be seen as an insult. (Not that your answer does answer the question). But I certainly can't change what you (want to) think. Nor am I interested in.

Comment: @tilz0R Why would anyone downvote correct answers, (unless they are in reply to terribru bad questions)?

Comment: @MartinJames no matter how stupid question is (there is no stupid questions at all), if it is correct, it is correct! StackOverflow is not "uf, answer was ok, but since question was terrible, let's downvote CORRECT answer". Doesn't sound stupid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C does not know about reference. Use pointers instead.

```
void fun_a(int *a, int *b) {
   *a = 10;
   *b = 12;
}

int main() {
    int x = 5, y = 6;
    printf("%d, %d\n", x, y);    // 5, 6
    fun_a(&x, &y);             // pass pointer to variable
    printf("%d, %d\n", x, y);    // 10, 12

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer : you can't.
To achieve your goal, you have to pass by pointer.